# How to dropout entire hidden layer in a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a neural network in tensorflow 2.0. There I want to dropout the whole hidden layer with
a probability not any single node with a certain probability. Can anyone please tell me how to dropout the entire layer in tensorflow 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `noise_shape` argument of the `Dropout` layer to be `[1] * n_dim` of the input. Let's say the input tensor is 2D:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.ones([3,5])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

`noise_shape` should be `[1, 1]`.

```
tf.nn.dropout(x, rate=.5, noise_shape=[1, 1])
```

Then randomly it will give either these as weights:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]], dtype=float32)>
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

You can test it like this with a Keras layer:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.5, noise_shape=[1, 1])(x, training=True)
```

If you use it in a model, just remove the `training` argument, and make sure you manually specify the `noise_shape`.

Something like this should work, although I haven't tested it:

```
class SubclassedModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubclassedModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        noise_shape = tf.ones(tf.rank(inputs))
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.5, 
                                    noise_shape=noise_shape)(inputs, training=training)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return x
```

Comment: what does training=True mean? why should I remove the training argument? Can you please explain this?

Comment: Dropout sets a %age of the weights to zero, so during training, the network is used to half of the input it will get while testing. And so a dropout layer has different behavior during training and testing. `Training=False` makes it output weights that will be useful during testing, and so I had to set it to `True` to demonstrate it here. Otherwise, it outputs only ones. Depending if you're using a functional, sequential, or subclassed model, you might have to deal with this argument differently. I suggest the subclassing approach because you need input shape for `noise_shape`.

Comment: I have a 4 dimensional input (batch size, number of frames, joints, joint dimensionality). Now should I use noise shape = [1,1,1,1]?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm suggesting